# Force Save As dialog on Safari browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have a webpage that displays image in an `<img>` tag. My client now wants to have a Save As dialog when someone clicks on the Save As button, so that the user can avoid right-clicking. I need it to work on the Safari browser. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the Content-Disposition HTTP header [(which can be found here)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html).

Specifically you need:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="fname.ext"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should implement changes on your server.
Using the header: `Content-Disposition`.

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=MyFileName.png
```

In ASP.NET

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=MyFileName.png");
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.But that is where i am facing a problem.i dont have physical location of the image.i have src of the image as byte array like this '0x49492A009E4F000093503684F9DA3BCB7175FFFFFFFF32EC8F97C8E6623065E3111CC8ECCD9B8C65F2ECB991F2F91CBFFF048117E0813F82845D2045F410229FA0409C178617FEFD5BFB5FB4852BBF1EFFFF5C1FFC20BC1FFF5B7075FFFD60BE2B8820582FFF561C17FFFFFE0817FFFFF0DFAFFFDF7AEFFFA6C1027ADC8FFEFFFFF6B636B8386C535EC541FFFC44444444444444444447FFFFF9D89B3......'

Comment: and when i am trying to use this-    context.Response.Headers["Content-Type"] = "image/tiff"; i am getting this error "This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode"

Comment: Use context.Response.Headers.AddHeader method instead. See this answer to output the bytes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3625607/208683

Comment: can not use that.  If i try to use i ll get this error -System.Collections.Specialized.nameValueCollection does Not contain a definition for AddHeader